# Linux screen input automatic response

Tags: linux, input, prompt

I have a python program that prompts for user keyboard input.  Based on the input, a certain section of code is completed.

```
List of items in this dfsu file:

1.  Significant Wave Height
2.  Peak Wave Height
3.  Wave Direction

Chose item from the list above
```

I want to always choose 1, and since this question is repeated 5000 times, I do not want to manually enter 1.  I don't have access to the source code to hardcode this, but I'm wondering if there is a way to force the user input to be 1 each time this question is asked?

Thanks,
Kimberly

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force the user input to be 1 each time this question is asked?

[`yes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29), there is.

Run `yes` and pipe its output to the command you run:

```
yes 1 | the_command_you_originally_ran
```

By default, `yes` outputs `y` repeatedly, assuming you want to auto-confirm "are-you-sure"-like prompts, but you can run `yes 1` to make it output `1` in an infinite loop.